# How to make SUM(A+B) without defining the row number?

Tags: excel, operations

I have in Excel a whole column field, where I have to set

for row 2: `SUM(A2+B2)`,

for row 3: `SUM(A3+B3)`...

Is there a fast way to set it to the whole column without having to insert it one by one in the fields?

Something like `SUM(A#+B#)`, where `#` automatically fills with the current row and number, so I can set the whole column automatically.

---

Also, how do I reference one worksheet in another worksheet?

Let's say I have a worksheet `dates` and worksheet `times`. I want the dates to appear in a field in the `times` worksheet, something like `VALUE(dates.A2)` in a field of `times`.

Comment: Please, be aware, that each post is meant to represent one question. When you have another one, consider [posting it separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Place the formula in **C2**, *=SUM(A2+B2)* .  Then move the cursor *(via mouse)* to the bottom right-corner of the cell.  When you see the cursor change from the "fat-plus" to the "thin-plus", double-click.

Column **C** will immediately populate with formulas with the proper reference adjusted.